# Locus of motion when looking at a fixed point. Alternate Conics definition

Tags: analytic-geometry

A person P moves such  that projection of his distance $ D$  to a fixed point C onto a fixed line L through C is proportional to distance left after removing  constant length $L$ from C. Find his path.

EDIT1

It may be of interest to note that 1/R is eccentricity and L is latus rectum for all conics in polar form. And the **question presents another new definition of conics without directrix**.

EDIT2:

[image]

A quick sketch on Geogebra verifies that ratio of (projected segment length on x-axis) to (focal ray length minus latus rectum segment length)  equals to chosen eccentricity $\epsilon$  of three constructed conics.

$$ \dfrac{r-p}{x}= \epsilon \quad ,\frac{EE_d}{Oe} =  \epsilon_{ell},\, \frac{PP_d}{Op} =  \epsilon_{par},\, \frac{HH_d}{Oh} =  \epsilon_{hyp}.\, $$

Comment: I think is a hyperbola. I write now my reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, let be L the polar axis, the fixed point C the origin and the coordinates of that person $P=(r,\theta)$. So, $D=r$. The projection onto L is $D\cos\theta$. $D-L$ is the diminished distance. So.

$$\frac{D\cos\theta}{D-L}=R$$

With $R$ the constant of proportionality.

$$D=\frac{RL}{R-\cos\theta}=\frac{L}{1-(1/R)\cos\theta}$$

It's an ellipse or a hyperbola depending on the value of the parameters.

Comment: How to subtract polar  axis?

Comment: I understand that the constant $L$ is substracted to the distance $D$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes But in the first line it is written it as an axis. Grammar?

Comment: Not sure about what you mean. L is the polar axis $L$ is the constant substracted.

Comment: OK, now got it, L is axis and $L$ is the line segment.Fine..